# iPhone simple question: How to call a method from the main-class?

Tags: ios, methods, delegates

I have following code:

```
     LoginViewController *lvc = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
 [self presentModalViewController:lvc animated:false];
 [lvc release];
```

That is called from my MainViewController.

Now, when the LoginViewController will be dismissed (of course this only happens when the login is correct) I must call a method in my MainViewController to load the initial data for my app.

I read a lot about delegate and tried it, but don't get it to work.
Could someone help me please?

(if possible, please with a few lines of code)
Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I read a lot about delegate and tried it, but don't get it to work.

What have you tried really? Your LoginViewController must define a simple delegate protocol, and your MainViewController must conform to it.

All you need to do is add something like this in LoginViewController.h above @interface:

```
@protocol LoginViewControllerDelegate

- (void)loginViewControllerDidFinish;

@end
```

Which declares a protocol with one method. Then add this between @interface and @end:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <LoginViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

Which means your login view controller will have a property called delegate which will point to an instance of any class (that's what id means) that conforms to it's delegate protocol (the thing between < and >). Don't forget to `@synthesize delegate;` inside .m file.

Now what you need to do is inside MainViewController.h add  to @interface line like this:

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <LoginViewControllerDelegate>
```

Which tells the compiler your MainViewController class conforms to this LoginViewControllerDelegate delegate protocol. Now implement the `- (void)loginViewControllerDidFinish;` method inside MainViewController.m and before presenting the login view controller modally set it's delegate to self (`login.delegate = self;`). When you are done inside your login view controller, before you dismiss it, call the delegate method on your delegate:

```
[self.delegate loginViewControllerDidFinish];
```

And that's it. Any more questions?

Comment: Thank you, I did the most things of this, the problem is, I can not set the delegate = self, because I use the Three20 Navigator to call the LoginViewController. Any ideas?

Comment: You mean from the instance of Three20 navigator? If that's the case your interface looks something like `@interface MainViewController : UIViewController`. Just add `<LoginViewControllerDelegate>` to the end of that line.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1) when pushing login view, set some flag in MainViewController

2) in method *viewWillAppear* in MainViewController check that flag from 1). If it is set then load the initial data and unset flag. Otherwise push LoginView.

Answer (score 1):

You've got an UIApplicationDelegate, and it should have an instance variable that points to the MainViewController. Expose this instance variable via a property, say `mainViewController` (on your UIApplicationDelegate), and then you can access it like this:

```
[(MyUIApplicationDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] mainViewController]
```